# javascript regex how to match this 'And' 'Or'

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string something like this:

`"q1" = "1" And "q2" = "2" oR "q3" = "3"`

I want to split it into a array:

`['"q1" = "1"',' And ', '"q2" = "2"',' oR ','"q3" = "3"']`

How can I do it with  regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for splitting with a capture group:

```
/( (?:and|or) )/i
```

**Code:**

```js
const str = `"q1" = "1" And "q2" = "2" oR "q3" = "3"`;
var arr = str.split(/( (?:and|or) )/i);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this case, it doesn't work.
"q1 or q2 and q3" = "1"  And "q4 and q5"  = "4"
How do I modify the regex to cover this?  Appreciate your help!

Comment: What is your expected output for input `"q1 or q2 and q3" = "1" And "q4 and q5" = "4"` ?

Comment: It gets complicated because this case is not covered in your original problem. You may try: `str.split(/( (?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(?:and|or) )/i)`

Comment: it worked on that case. but doesn't work in this case
`"Little interest or pleasure in doing things?"="0"AND "Feeling down, depressed, or hopeless?" >= "2"`

Comment: this `( (?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(?:and|or) )/i)` doesn't seem like general enough to handle the format like this:   `"{{question}}"  {{operator}} "{{answer}}"  {{logic}} (which is optional)`

Comment: Please don't change requirements from comments section. Original solution was posted with assumption that there are no `and/or` keywords inside quotes. It would be better you create a new question and include all new data so that we can build best answer for you.